# how can i creat a list of clickable images on android

Tags: android

i am reallly new on android , what can i use to creat a list of images that when i click on one of them i add it to another list like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHGaz.png)

i just want an idea like , do i need listview or something else becaus i dont know how can make 3 images in one line in a list view or use a grid of images but how can i hide the grid and only show it when i chose the list i want to show because i will have about 4 grid of images 
like this when i click fruit et légumes it shows a list of images and then when i click viandes et piosson it shows antoher list of iamges 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeAZr.png)

this what i have tried making a list with only strings that i add by clicking a button and know i want to devlope this like the image

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);

        mShoppingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_listView);
        mItemEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_editText);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mShoppingList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item = mItemEdit.getText().toString();
                final String Art=item;
                mAdapter.add(item);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mItemEdit.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `RecyclerView` and a `GridLayoutManager`. This will get you the correct view that you want.

Here is a link that demonstrates these two `views` working together [RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

As for clicking on one and removing it from the list, that is something you will need to handle inside of the `Adapter`.

Comment: THANKKK YOU SIR thats what i need